# Stata Incidence Rate Ratios

Tags: stata, survival-analysis

```
webuse stan3
stset
stptime
stptime, by(surgery)
stir surgery
```

My objective is to estimate incidence rate ratios for surgery vs non surgery but in a setting when I have individual-level sample weights to weight up to a population of interest. How can I estimate the incidence rate ratios while incorporating these sample weights?

Comment: Before running your survival model, you can specify weights using `stset`. From the help-file for `stcox`: "fweights, iweights, and pweights may be specified using stset"

Comment: @Cybernike I would make that an answer.

Comment: @Cybernike I get an error when I try to do this: stir does not allow pweights

set seed 98034
generate WEIGHT = trunc(runiform()*1000)
stset stime[pweight = WEIGHT], id
stptime
stptime, by(surgery)
stir surgery

Comment: @NickCox I get an error when I try to do this: stir does not allow pweights

set seed 98034
generate WEIGHT = trunc(runiform()*1000)
stset stime[pweight = WEIGHT], id
stptime
stptime, by(surgery)
stir surgery

Comment: Not something I ever do....